# How to authenticate websocket chat by JWT

Tags: spring, websocket, jwt, chat, stomp

I have a functional project of chat by websockets that is already working, now I need to implement authentication by JWT. This is the flow of the requests

1. Client connects to `ws://localhost:port/chatting`
2. Client subscribes to its own inbox, in order to receive messages from other clients: `/user/{userId}/queue/chatting`
3. Client can send messages to other users in /app/message by specifying in body:
   `{ 'message': msg, 'from': "userId", 'to': "recipientId" }`, and the system will redirect them to `/user/{recipientId}/queue/chatting`

I would like to secure:

1. A user has to authenticate in order to **do the handshake**
2. A user has to be "userId" in order to **subscribe** to /user/"userId"/queue/chatting, so that other users can't access it.
3. A user has to be "userId" in order to **send** a message to another user with "userId" in `from` inside body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all adding authentication can be done by configuring the same in `WebSecurityConfig` , adding a custom `JwtRequestFilter` which is going to parse you JWT token and set the authentication context for that request.

A good reference for the same: [create-apis-with-jwt-authorization-using-spring-boot](https://dev.to/cuongld2/create-apis-with-jwt-authorization-using-spring-boot-24f9).

Regarding 2 and 3, Springboot does not allow exposing dynamic endpoints for STOMP registration, so you will have to expose `/user/queue/chatting` and clients will have to directly subscribe to this. However, using [convertAndSendToUser(userId, destination, payload)](http://https:/https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/78d1591e2ddfe01f05b9d09e68a00e7ad54c885a/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.java#L203) you can send the message based on the userId. This function internally calls [this function](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/78d1591e2ddfe01f05b9d09e68a00e7ad54c885a/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.java#L230) which  does this `this.destinationPrefix(/user) + user(/username) + destination(/queue/chatting)` so as you can see the variable `user` is getting prefixed to final destination, you can pass userId instead of userName.

Reference for this: [simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html#convertAndSendToUser-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

But do note in this case you would have to set the username for this session as userId itself. This can be done in your custom `JwtRequestFilter`

```
private void populateSecurityContextHolder(HttpServletRequest request, String userId, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
                userId, null, grantedAuthorities);
        authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
        log.info("Authentication set for userId " + userId);
    }
```

So with this, your server can send messages based on userId it receives in the messages.

Comment: I've developed already part of your solution. However, there's one point that is not clear to me. How can a user subscribe to user/queue/chatting but in reallity he's subscribing to user/userId/queue/chatting? How can I do this in Spring boot?

Comment: That is a property of a `/user` endpoint. As i said earlier when you `convertAndSendToUser` it automatically adds the username to the destination: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/78d1591e2ddfe01f05b9d09e68a00e7ad54c885a/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.java#L230, basically while subscribing you subsribe to a common destination however while sending a message springboot prefixes the username(or userid inyour case) and sends it.